# Rails 4: Is there a simple way to create a select box to display ranges of integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, input, range

I have a field in my form

```
<%= f.input :cases, collection: 0..500, label: "Number of new cases of ILD per month (approx)", class: 'form-control' %>
```

The data type in the DB is integer. Is there a clever Rails/Ruby way of creating ranges in the select such that......0-50, 51-100, 101-150 etc. with the database set up as it is? My users are asking for this.

Comment: I guess I could use and alias integer.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use a selector for so many integer options, but rather an editable increment/decrement box with min set to 0 and max set to 500.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance....editable increment/decrement box? What is this? Like a bar with a min/max? I have 50 of these select boxes, so your solution could be really helpful.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't using the right term. It's called a "spin edit". It's a regular edit box with a little up and down arrow buttons next to it for incrementing/decrementing the value. Ideal for setting an integer value that can take on a wide range. Are you using any particular forms gems, like [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)? Many of them have helpers for controls like that. If the user needs to select one specific value within the 0 to 500 range, that's probably the optimum control for doing it.